Should I upgrade my linux kernel?
I recently updated an older computer to use Ubuntu 24.04. My current kernel version is Linux 6.5.0-35-generic.
The apt repository currently provides multiple versions of linux-tools, ranging from linux-tools-6.8.0-31 to linux-tools-6.8.0-41. But it does not provide linux-tools-6.5.0-35.
Is it a good idea for me to update my Linux kernel to 6.8.0-41 if I want to use tools like perf that depend on having linux-tools installed?

I'm pretty sure kernel line 6.5 doesn't get security updates anymore, so definitely yes!!

Ubuntu 24.04 starts at kernel 6.8, so it's curious that your system remains on an older, unsupported kernel. Unless you did it intentionally, it suggests an incomplete or partial release-upgrade that you should investigate.

It wasn't intentional. I'm not sure what happened.

Did you reboit after your upgrade?  Are you sure the upgrade succeeded?

I have been using Ubuntu 24.04 for over a month and have rebooted several times since then. My "Settings -> About -> Operating System" shows "Ubuntu 24.04 LTS". uname -sr shows Linux 6.5.0-35-generic. Please recommend how I can debug this.

I have attempted to install the linux-image-generic package through the apt repository, and it successfully installed 6.8.0-31 alongside 6.5.0-38, I can see the kernels side by side in my BIOS window when I start. However, when I launch the new image, basic functionality such as touchpad and networking is broken and I am not sure how to install the appropriate drivers.

I will ask a new question.

Keep your system offline, as the 6.5 kernel is NOT supported by Ubuntu, and should have been upgraded as it's a mantic or 23.10 kernel only. If you're still using it, you've broken your system somehow (manual pinning I suspect preventing upgrade), and you have outdated internet safety any longer as 23.10 is EOL so stay offline until fixed.
